# Split CSV string in javascript with extra ","

Tags: javascript

How to split in javascript this string

```
s = "Shares Mil,"6,143","6,225","6,315"
```

in this array:

```
["6,143", "6,225", "6,315"]
```

`s.split(',')` doesn't work because gives:

```
["6", "143", "6", "225", "6", "315"]
```

Comment: Guessing that you might need to use Regex.

Comment: Comes from the console.... Fixed.

Comment: That's not a valid javascript string.  What is the real value of `s`?  Perhaps you have some `\"` in there?

Comment: Please use the search before you ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it by Regex:

```
var rx = /("[^"]*")(?:[,$])/g
var a = s.match(rx)
```